# How to get model object without relational model object in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing prject in Laravel. I have model named 'Property' contains,

```
public function PropertyRatings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Property\PropertyRating','property_id','id');
    }
```

In controller, when I do like,

```
if(empty($property->PropertyRatings))
{
   $property->flag = 0;
}else
{
   $property->flag = $property->PropertyRatings->id;
}
```

In this case when I returned my property object then that case I am getting the response with PropertyRatings object as well. How can I prevent getting this in this case only. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) -

```
unset($property->PropertyRatings);
```

Comment: Hey its working, but can you tell me, is there any way to prevent getting this in laravel?

Comment: eloquent do this trick automatically, i think we should not alter their core code, right??

Comment: Okay I thought they had provide some function or something to prevent getting this :)